# Pure CSS solution to push the middle of 3 items down

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Okay, my situation is as following:

I have 3 divs in a row using flexbox:
`1 | 2 | 3`

The width of div `1` is fixed. Div `2` 'flexes' to take the available space between `1` and `3`, but should minimally be the size of its contents (which varies). div `3` needs to be the width of the content it contains, which varies.

So I have:

```
1 (fixed with) | 2 (flexes, but minimal width should be the width of the content) | 3 (width of content)
```

What I want to achieve is that if the container in which all three divs sit becomes too small too fulfill the minimal width requirements of each div, then the middle part (div `2`) is pushed down. So I get:

```
1 | 3
-----
  2
```

I know how I could achieve this using javascript, but is this possible using a pure CSS solution, knowing that I do not know the width of the contents of `2` and `3` beforehand?

Here's a codepen which does not yet do what I want, but could be used as a starting point to save you some time: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grBwEp

Note: I know how I can get either `1 | 2 | 3` or

```
 1 | 3
 -----
   2
```

by changing the `order` properties. However, I can't have fixed breakpoints for the switch, since I don't know the width of the content, and the content varies...

Comment: you can change the order of div like 1, 3, and then 2 so it can be easy to fix using css

Comment: @AtifAzad No, becuase then they will also be `1 | 3 | 2` if they are on one row. And I can't change the order based on breakpoints, since I don't know the width.

Comment: check the answer below

Comment: Since you cant use media queries, the answer is no, there is no CSS Flexbox solution. CSS cannot detect overflow to change the order.

Comment: Yeah. I've been playing around with this for hours.. Can be done only with JS....

Answer (score 0):

You can force the 2nd child (`child2`) to be in a new line if you add `width: 100%` and order it last (`order: 3`) which looks like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container > div.child1 {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  order: 1;
}

.container > div.child2 {
  background-color: blue;
  order: 3;
  width:100%;
}

.container > div.child3 {
  background-color: green;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1">1 (fixed width)</div>
  <div class="child2">2 (flexes, but minimal width should be the width of the content)</div>
  <div class="child3">3 (width of content)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but this is a fixed solution. Now, it won't switch between the 2 scenarios. And I can't use media queries, since I don't know the width of the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a media query for the size you want to react with. Here an example of 600px width:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container > div.child1,
  .container > div.child3 {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    width: auto;
  }
  .container > div.child2 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    order: 4;
  }
}
```

Here a forked Version of your Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNgRKa/left

Comment: I can't use breakpoints, since I don't know the width I have to break at, since the content is variable.

Answer (score 0):

well here is the solution

```
<style>
.one, .two {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left
}
.three {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: right
}
.one {
    background: #999;
}
.two {
    background: #060;
}
.three {
    background: #336;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.two {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
}
</style>
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="one">01</div>
<div class="three">03</div>
<div class="two">02</div>
```

Comment: you can play with div i just use randomly width in percent

Comment: OP wants first div to have a fixed width of 150px and also no media queries.

Comment: use this css hope it can help you ----->

.one, .two { float:left}
.three { float:right}
.one { background:#999; width:150px;}
.two { background:#060;}
.three { background:#336;}